# Is there a way in R to find percent overlap between every combination of factors?

Tags: r, correlation

I'm looking for a way to build a table similar to a correlogram, but instead of showing correlation between variables it would show which percent of factors overlap between two variables for each combination of factors.

For example, using the variables 2018 and 2019, I'm trying to find the percent of factors that were "5" in 2018 AND 2019, percent that were "5" in 2018 but "4" in 2019, etc.

Sample of my data:

```
mydata <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
   LC_2018    LC_2019
   5          5
   3          3
   5          3
   6          5
   1          6")
```

[Example of the type of table I'm trying to build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qrMG.png)

I've tried using the veccompare package in R, but can only get it to compare the total percent overlap between 2018 and 2019 rather than percent overlap between each factor individually.

Hopefully this makes sense, and many thanks in advance for any advice or ideas anyone can share!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
prop.table(table(mydata$LC_2018, mydata$LC_2019), 1)

     3   5   6
  1 0.0 0.0 1.0
  3 1.0 0.0 0.0
  5 0.5 0.5 0.0
  6 0.0 1.0 0.0
```